# When do you get eth when mining eth?

Tags: mining, cpp-ethereum, claymore

I ran Claymore's eth miner for 8 hours and got 200 shares. I set my eth address when I ran the miner, but no eth was deposited to my address. When I restarted the miner the shares were reset to 0.

When will I get eth? How do I know if I'm mining right? Are my shares saved?

*Edit:* I'm not sure which pool I used earlier. I'm looking for a pool now. What happens when I set the pool and mine. How many shares do I need to get eth? If I stop the miner are all my shares lost?

This is my config.txt

```
-epool ? 
-ewal 0x8A9cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-epsw x
-dpool ?stratum+tcp://yiimp.ccminer.org:4252
-dwal DsUt9QagrYLvSkJHXCvhfiZHKafVtzd7Sq4
-dpsw x
-esm 1
-mode 0
-tt 70
-asm 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically Claymore's eth miner need to be connected to a mining pool to get rewards base on the work your miner is doing.

You will get Eth when you reach the minimal payment threshold of the pool, I can pm you some good pools which a low threshold if you want.

Claymore's log should be clear if you mine well. But if you are getting shares, you should be mining right. 
Using a mining pool interface can provide to you more informations about your miner.

Your shares are kept by the mining pool.